# Responsive Images with jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a `jquery` animation that overlays an air-balloon on a map.
The air-balloon needs to "take off" and "land" in a specific points.

I need to make it responsive and here is the problem: How to make the points self-adjustable depending on the map size? (for the map image to be responsive I'm using `bootstrap` class `img-responsive`)
I'll also need to make the balloon size responsive, but I already have in mind I'll need to use `CSS Media Types` for that.

Anyone knows any library that already do that or have any idea?

---

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3350/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `isherwood` answer I found a way:

http://jsfiddle.net/w2XdZ/6/

Answer (score 1):

By establishing your points as percentages you remove image size as a factor.

jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w2XdZ

```
// Fix Balloon Initial Position
$("#balloon").css({
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    position: 'absolute'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the light! Please check my answer if do you think it's a good approach.